# How to disable the release notes in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs

Is there a simple setting to disable the release notes in the startup screen, rather than modifying the core.el here? https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/core/core-spacemacs-buffer.el#L360

Comment: Have you tried toggling the `[Release Notes]` link in the spacemacs buffer and restarting?  If I use that to toggle the notes off, they don't display when I start spacemacs again.

Comment: That is the solution @ngm

Comment: Great - I've added it as an answer then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can toggle the [Release Notes] link in the spacemacs buffer to hide the release notes - they should stay hidden after restarting from now on.